# Cron produces different results than when a file is run manually?

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am totally stumped.  I have a file that I need to run twice a day that queries a database and sends me an email if certain conditions are met.

This file, let's call it abc.php, works perfectly if I type "www.mysite.com/abc.php" into the browser the file runs perfectly.  If the conditions are met, I get an email that says (for example) "So and so, here's the info:  a, b, c."

But when I call the file with cron, for some reason the emails are garbled.  I get the "So and so, here's the info part" but not the "a, b, c."

I'm totally stumped.  The "So and so" is also coming from the database, and since that shows in both spots I know that the db query is working.

I can't see why something would WORK fine in a http call but not work when called via cron.  Are there permissions that should be set differently?  Directory trees that are described in a different way?  Should I use full pathways instead of relative ones?

In searching I found one issue that seems to be connected to php.ini files being different but I don't think that's the case here since I'm getting one db query fine.  I don't think this is a coding issue since it works perfectly when called from the browser.  But I do suspect it may be caused by the paths being incorrectly set or perhaps cron running as a different user or needing different permissions.

Any help or suggestions would be great.

Edit:  Here's the cron line.  Can I edit it to match whatever php.ini is being used when I run the file from the browser?

```
/ramdisk/bin/php5 -c /my/home/php.ini /my/home/sendmetheemail.php
```

Is it also possible that it's using a different mysql config file?  The php part seems to be working fine, but it's the data that's problematic.

Just tested and wget works fine:

```
wget http://mydomain.com/sendmetheemail.php
```

Comment: Please include your code.. we can't help without any code

Comment: How do you execute the cronjob? The execution is completely different if you pass the script directly to the interpreter versus performing a HTTP call (through wget, for example)

Comment: Probably, you have 2 different configs for `console` php and for `httpd`. Please, check your php.ini

Comment: are you using $_SERVER .... ?

Comment: These are exactly what I'm thinking might be wrong.  Is there a way to tell which php.ini file is being used by each?  I am definitely doing it directly, rather than with wget.  If I do wget, does it have to be within web root?  I would ideally like to have it above web root for security.  (Currently, it's in public_html).

Comment: Post the contents of sendmetheemail.php.

Comment: If it works in your browser and wget (essentially a browser), then it's like there are request variables somewhere in your script.

Do you see, $_REQUEST/$_SERVER/$_GET anywhere?

Is so, that's your problem.

Comment: The only variable is $_SESSION.  Would this be the cause?  (It actually looks to be right in the spot that could be messing up...)  Is there a way to rewrite so that it doesn't use that?

Comment: Is there a trick to posting the code that doesn't involve adding 4 spaces to each and every single line?  Or can I post (ideally) some snippits that might be useful rather than the whole .php file?  It's quite a long file.

Comment: Trick to posting code?  Highlight the code and click the {} button.

Answer (score 0):

You have a single file that you assume should run identically, but is producing different results, so obviously your assumption is wrong.

When I run into this predicament, I use a bunch of `syslog(LOG_INFO,"Display some data.");` lines in my code.  Check the results between them when run via cron verses directly.  If everything is the same, you haven't reached your problem.